# Float value returning from csv file as 0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to parse a csv file from url to record it through my DB then via this database I must create a html page table on rails contains and lists the info from csv file.

The problem is every value returning fine but one float parameter is blank at the table.

This is my migration

```rb
class CreateHmrcRates < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :hmrc_rates do |t|
      t.string :country
      t.string :currency
      t.string :curr_code
      t.float :units_per_pound
      t.datetime :start_date
      t.datetime :end_date

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This is my Controller

```rb
require 'open-uri'
require 'csv'

class HmrcRatesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @hmrc_rates = HmrcRate.all
  end

  def new
    csv_text = URI.open('https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/988629/exrates-monthly-0621.csv'){ |io| io.read.encode("UTF-8", invalid: :replace) }
    csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers=>true)
    csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
      HmrcRate.create(country: row["Country/Territories"], currency: row["Currency"], curr_code: row["Currency Code"], units_per_pound: row["Currency units per £1"].to_f, start_date: Date.parse(row["Start Date"]), end_date: Date.parse(row["End Date"]))
      puts "#{i}. #{row}"
      puts "***********************"
    end
    redirect_to hmrc_rates_path, notice: "HMRC rates created"
  end
end
```

at first it was like this

```rb
units_per_pound: row["Currency units per £1"]
```

this couldn't pass Validation:

> units_per_pound can not be blank

so I tried

```rb
units_per_pound: row["Currency units per £1"].to_f
```

This didn't trigger validation but when I checked in command prompt all float values recorded as `0.0`

My rails page looks like this

[image: My rails page looks like this]

Can you help me get my precious float values? Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: You are likely accessing a wrong column (i.e. you are using a different column name than what is in your CSV). Accessing the cell values for the non-existing column then results in `nil` being returned. And `nil.to_f` is `0.0`

Comment: My first guess would be that the column name is ending up not matching, perhaps because of the £ symbol. See if accessing it by column number works.

Comment: @HolgerJust The thing is the name in CSV of the column is exactly this; "Currency units per £1". But it was getting corrupted because of the "£" sign (there was a question mark box character instead), I think because off comma seperated and UTF-8 difference. So i tried to fix that used even 'charlock_holmes' and in the command prompt i finally could see the £ sign. So I don't know how else I match the column names.

Comment: @DaveNewton how can I do that?

Comment: @Kvothe28 `row[n]` where `n` is the column number (I don't know if it's 0- or 1-based; you might want to check the docs). Instead of trying to create the models at this point why not just attempt to read/parse the CSV and print it out on the console? One step at a time.

Comment: CSV isn't very reliable. You might want to use the XML versions instead: http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/softwaredevelopers/2021-exrates.html

Comment: @stefan I know but my task is specifically about parsing a csv file. I got that but now, just one £ sign messing up the whole document ecryption and my code.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by _"isn't very reliable"_ :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV file you are downloading is NOT UTF-8 encoded. Instead, it appears to be encoded in Windows-1252 (although you might want to check the documentation for the API if available). Because of that, the name of the header is not correct if you interpret the incoming data as UTF-8. As you have specified that invalid characters should be replaced with a replacement character on reading, the `£` character is read incorrectly by your code.

You can fix this by specifying the correct encoding when reading the file into a string and then re-encoding the string into your desired target encoding:

```
csv_uri = 'https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/988629/exrates-monthly-0621.csv'
csv_text = URI.open(csv_uri, encoding: "Windows-1252").read.encode('UTF-8')
```

Here, we specify that the data as read by `URI.open` is supposed to be `Windows-1252` encoded. In the second step, we re-encode this data to UTF-8.

Now, you can use the rest of your code to parse the `csv_text`. As we are now using the correct encoding, we can use the correct header names:

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  puts "#{row['Country/Territories']} - #{row['Currency units per £1 ']}"
end
```

Note that the specified header name for the currency units has a trailing space in the file. As such, you have to also specify this trailing space when accessing the value in the `CSV::Row` object.

If you do not want to be dependent on header names but can be sure that the order of columns doesn't change, you can also use numeric indexes rather than names to access he cells in a row:

```
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
  puts "#{row[0]} - #{row[3]}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! After a little bit of tweaking with the code now I can get all values using "puts" on the command prompt. But i need it also in that HTML and I don't know how to transfer the values. I tried to inject to the DB with "HmrcRate.create" but it returned this error; (ArgumentError in HmrcRatesController#new
When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument, String passed.) And btw I found out that document was encoded by "ISO-8859-1" by using charlock holmes.